# Prevent user entering a certain character on search bar

Tags: ios, special-characters, uisearchbar, nscharacterset

Is it possible to prevent the user to enter certain characters on search bar while typing. For example, the user types some string... `"This is a text "` and after word text the user tries enter an `'*'` character. I wish to prevent the user from entering that character.

Is it possible to restrict the user to enter a certain character while typing on a search bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UISearchBar` has a delegate much like the one for `UITextField`. Implement the delegate's `searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method. Return `YES` or `NO` as needed. If you return `NO`, the text won't be entered.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    // check the resulting text. Return NO if not allowed
}
```

Comment: I will try this out. But does this stop entering the entire text? I just want to stop the user for a character, but he should be able to enter/use the text entered prior to that character. I will play around with this method to see how it works.

Comment: I will try this. But when i used this delegate method searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) was not called when clicking in keyboard search button. How to solve this??